# cannot access context menu on mac

Tags: osx

in view layer I've tried to right click collection to access context menu, nothing. I've tried pressing W on keyboard, nothing. I'm using mac mouse (not magic mouse) being sure I have selected the emulate three button mouse but it didn't make any difference. Please need suggestion on how to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and no real answer I purchased a cheap PC mouse that will also work with Mac os, the menus appear as they should. Guess Mac mouse just wasn't going to work!